"no such column: rowid" error with Django 4.2 and Spatialite 5.0.1
I am upgrading an application from Django 3.2 to 4.2, which uses postgis in production, and django.contrib.gis.db.backends.spatialite when running unit tests.
Running the tests on this application, I'm getting this error:
django.db.utils.OperationalError: error in trigger ISO_metadata_reference_row_id_value_insert: no such column: rowid
make: *** [django.mk:49: test] Error 1

This problem is documented in this ticket, and seems to be an issue with using Django 4.2 and Spatialite 5: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/32935
One of the workarounds looks like executing this command in the spatialite database:
./manage.py shell -c "import django;django.db.connection.cursor().execute('SELECT InitSpatialMetaData(1);')";

However, after I run this command, I am still getting the no such column: rowid error. Has anyone else run into this? I am using Django 4.2.11, sqlite 3.42.0, libspatialite 5.0.1, python 3.12.2 on Fedora Linux.

The problem was normally solved in spatialite 5.1, so upgrading to that version should solve your problem.
Reference: https://groups.google.com/g/spatialite-users/c/E5KwsEgP4_E/m/AG3gyl1RAgAJ
